# stl: резервирование элементов вектора при его создании

Tags: c++, оптимизация, vector, stl

подскажите, можно ли выполнить резервирование (выделение) элементов вектора в момент его создания, т.е. вместо

```
std::vector<int> arr;
arr.reserve(size);
```

выполнить как-то в одну команду

отчасти задача нужна для следующего:

есть функция

```
void func(
    std::vector<int>&& arr = std::vector<int>()
)
{}
```

и хотелось бы, чтобы если параметр `arr` не указан, то формировался вектор с зарезервированными элементами

конечно задачу можно решить следующим образом (как мне кажется):

```
void func(
    std::vector<int>&& arr = std::vector<int>()
)
{
    if (arr.size() == 0) {
        arr.reserve(size);
    }
}
```

но это выглядит как-то немного топорно

Comment: Уже где-то тут обсуждалось, что даже при копировании резервирование не копируется (перемещение не рассматривалось, насколько я помню). И еще - `reserve` соответствует не `size`, а `capacity`.

Comment: Ага, при перемещении вроде бы сохраняется... https://ideone.com/omFXzx Но все равно конструктора с резервированием памяти нет. Разве что создадите свой вектор - наследник стандартного :)

Comment: А что мешает сделать перегрузку вместо передачи аргумента по-умолчанию.

Comment: @Harry, `size` - это просто переменная, просто чтобы не писать какое-то число тут

Comment: @user7860670, ничто не мешает, просто интересно - есть ли стандартные средства, ведь можно же например создать вектор из 100 нулевых элементов, хотя резервирование все таки наверное экзотика и для нее не стали делать какие-то специальные конструкторы и т.п.

Comment: @Zhihar, все таки наверное экзотика....

Comment: Дают вам землю и семена, а вы решайте сколько участка выделите для посева. Вы можете взять землю конкретного размера, только для посева этого зерна, но и можете после  
планировать размер ожидаемого участка. Ситуация аналогичная и логичная.

Comment: Я об `if (arr.size()`

Comment: Предложенные ответы явно длиннее, чем просто вызвать `reserve()` и не мучиться...

Comment: *`"вместо `* `std::vector<int> arr; arr.reserve(size);` *`выполнить как-то в одну команду"`* -- написать макрос?

Answer (score 3):

Всё вроде-бы просто, принимаете новый вектор (r-value) из другой функции.

```
# include <vector>
std::vector<int> makevector() {
  std::vector<int> arr;
  size_t size = 100 ;
  arr.reserve(size);
  return  arr ; }

void func(
    std::vector<int>&& arr = makevector()
)
{}
```

---

Если у вас функция `func` не рекурсивная и вам нужна скорость, то можно этот аргумент по-умолчанию хранить в "кеше" (запасной статической переменной). Тогда использование кеша даст большую помощь.

```
std::vector<int> && makevector(void) {
  static  thread_local  std::vector<int> arr;
  arr.clear();
  size_t size = 100 ;
  arr.reserve(size);
  return  std::move(arr) ; }
```

Comment: интересный подход

Comment: Не забывайте, что вектор `&& arr` имеет короткое время жизни. (до конца функции `func`).

Comment: посмотрите ещё ускорение, из-за статического кеша.

Answer (score 2):

Специального конструктора нет.

Или делать так: (выглядит не очень, честно говоря)

```
void func(std::vector<int> &&arr = []{std::vector<int> ret; ret.reserve(42); return ret;}())
{

}
```

Или писать вторую перегрузку.

Comment: Это ничем не лучше, чем просто вызов. С перегрузкой согласен.

Answer (score 1):

Можно так, ещё std::move где-то может потребоваться.

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> reserved_vector(size_t sz)
{
    auto vec = std::vector<T>();
    vec.reserve(sz);
    return vec;
}

void func(
    std::vector<int>&& arr = reserved_vector<int>(10)
)
{}
```

Comment: `vec` перемещается автоматически, `move` не нужен. Он даже вреден, потому что убирает возможность NRVO.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat как с мувом, так и без него выходит одинаковый ассемблерный код у меня.

Comment: Из-за [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) ассемблерный код не обязан зависеть от количества перемещений (особенно со включенной оптимизацией, особенно когда перемещающий конструтор инлайновый, и компилятор видит, что он не делает ничего интересного). Лишнее перемещение - есть, и если компилятор не может доказать, что его убирание ни на что не влияет, то он его не уберет: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/v6jWMe